# How to assign the results of Meteor.call to a variable-Meteor

Tags: meteor

If I have the following code:

```js
Meteor.call('/firstURL/abcd', xxx, function(err, result) {          
    if (err) {
        //...
    } else {    
        Meteor.call('/secondURL/acde', zzz,  function(err, result) {
            if (err) {
                //..
            } else {  
                valueneeded=result
            } 
        });             
    }           
});
console.log(valueneeded)       //undefined
```

How to get variable

> valueneeded

outside the asynchrnous call ?

Comment: On the server or on the client?

Comment: On the client, you can't. Explain what you'd like to achieve, and we'll try to help you figure out the next step. But for now, just put your console.log inside the callback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See also [Blaze template iterate over object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42615724/blaze-template-iterate-over-object/42618922#42618922) (also applicable to any situation, not just within a Blaze template)

With Meteor, you can also use a `ReactiveVar` to receive the result of your asynchronous call. If your code that makes use of it is within a reactive scope (like a `Tracker.autorun`), it will be re-executed when data arrives.

This assumes that you can live with that code being executed several times (initially while your call is still pending a response, then once it completes)